# How to make a Link inside an iframe open in new tab

Tags: html, css, iframe

so I have a web page I've been working on that uses embedded Google Docs in an iFrame to keep it updated without having to hard code notices/updates.

I came across a problem, where if you were to click on a link it opens in the iframe instead of opening in a new tab, which is preferable. I've tried things like:

```
<base target="_blank" />
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? (Note that with Google docs I can't find a way to change the way links are handled, so I'd need to do that on the end of the main page.)

Comment: I'd make an eventlistener with javascript and when the user clicks, check if the click was in the iframe. If thats the case, get the link and open it in a new tab. I don't know if that really works, however. You may do some searches.

Comment: Would JS be able to know the link clicked in the iframe?

Comment: After a short search i don't think so. You have to find another solution. You may search for get parameters for google docs. For example if you use a yt video in an iframe you can set settings like fullscreen, autoplay etc. Have you already checked out this possibility?

Comment: I have not checked out that possibility, I'll go check that out now. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll let you know if something comes up

Comment: I did some research and so far I haven't found any parameters to help with my dilemma.